# Convert deprecated Perl's Net::IRC codes to AnyEvent::IRC::Client inquiry

Tags: perl, irc, anyevent

Since the Perl's Net::IRC library's been deprecated, I need to convert some old code that uses it over to the newer AnyEvent::IRC::Client. The problem is that the MetaCPAN's AnyEvent docs. don't show any equivalence to the IRC numeric event codes and the add_global_handler() and add_handler() methods that Net::IRC supports. So, for example, what would be the equivalent of the following Net::IRC code snippets in AnyEvent::IRC::Client's syntax? Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
my $irc = new Net::IRC ;
my $conn = $irc->newconn( Server => ..., Port => ..., Nick => ... ) ;
$conn->add_global_handler( [ 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 302 ], \&on_init ) ;
$conn->add_global_handler( [ 422, 376 ], \&on_connect ) ;
$conn->add_handler( 'crping', \&on_ping_reply ) ;
$conn->add_handler( 'caction', \&on_action ) ;
...
$irc->start ;
```

The docs for AnyEvent::IRC::Client ( ref: https://metacpan.org/pod/AnyEvent::IRC::Client ) only provides reg_cb() method and no IRC numeric code handler, so below is all I have so far for the new codes:

```
my $condVar = AnyEvent->condvar ;
my $conn = AnyEvent::IRC::Client->new() ;
$conn->connect( $server, $port, ... ) ;
$conn->reg_cb( crping => sub { ... } ) ;
$conn->reg_cb( caction => sub { ... } ) ;

my $timer = AnyEvent->timer (
  after => $twoSecs ,
  cb => sub {
    $conn->disconnect ;
    $condVar->send ;
  }#end callback
) ;#end timer
$condVar->recv ;
undef( $timer ) ;
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you having? We answer specific questions; we're not a software-writing service.

Comment: @ikegami, as stated, I could NOT find any documentation on how to handle IRC's event numeric codes in AnyEvent::IRC:Client.

Comment: Thx @toolic, per the samples, looks like I can use the "irc_<codeNumber>" to handle event numeric code. But still no equivalent to Net::IRC's specific add_global_handler() VS. add_handler() methods.

Answer (score 3):

Your post lacks a clear queston. In fact, your question appears to be in the comments, and it's not even phrased as a question.

> *I could NOT find any documentation on how to handle IRC's event numeric codes in AnyEvent::IRC:Client*

This is supported by the fact that the only part missing from the second snippet appears to be the following:

```perl
$conn->add_global_handler( [ 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 302 ], \&on_init ) ;
$conn->add_global_handler( [ 422, 376 ], \&on_connect ) ;
```

So I'm assuming you're asking how to handle those events with AnyEvent::IRC::Client.

---

The source and the samples included in the distribution both suggest you can use the following:

```perl
$conn->reg_cb("irc_$_" => \&on_init) for 251..255, 302;
$conn->reg_cb("irc_$_" => \&on_connect) for 376, 422;
```

If not, you can use the following to discover the appropriate identifier:

```perl
$conn->reg_cb(debug_recv => sub {
   my ($msg) = @_;
   say STDERR "Received irc_" . lc($msg->{command});
});
```

---

Upon further study of the code, `irc_001`, `irc_376` and `irc_422` result in the `welcome` event being fired, so the following would be a better solution:

```perl
$conn->reg_cb("irc_$_" => \&on_init) for 251..255, 302;
$conn->reg_cb(welcome => \&on_connect);
```

Also note that AnyEvent::IRC::Client already handles ping messages from the server.